# Parse/Read html data. Check if the fourth <td> is empty then read the next <td> data on to a word

Tags: html, parsing

I have a html page with 20-25 tables [each seperate table] which has 0-10 entries. I have to read 5th column data only if the fourth  is empty. I need to check for all the tables in the page. what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your question is too general I'm afraid, some may help, but generally for SO you need to ask a very specific question to a problem, not basically can somebody do this for me.  Which let's be honest, this kind of is.  Show some code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can do this with "web scraping". You need a little script in C or in Python or... whatever..
E.g. - (in Python)

```
import urllib2

#specify the url to check  
wiki = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

#Query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib2.urlopen(wiki)

#import the Beautiful soup functions to parse the data from the website
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Parse the html in the 'page' variable, and store it in Beautiful Soup format
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
.....
.....
```